# jfreechart different series color

Tags: dataset, jfreechart

I have `XYAreaChart` and a `dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();`
This dataset is populated with several XYSeries and i want each one of these series to have a different color. The series can overlapse each other.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

I tried a number of things and it keeps painting everything with the same color.

Comment: Post some code, please, so we can see what you have tried.

Comment: The `DefaultDrawingSupplier` provides a new color for each series.